# How can I show ViewController in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a UITabBarController and all my other view controllers are connected to it. Now I want to show one my controller as:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
```

but when I tried to:

```
let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
rootViewController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

it gave me the next error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1a899b818) to 'UINavigationController'
```

Later I've tried to do:

```
let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

but in this case I get

```
UITabBar has no member pushViewController
```

How can I show/push my ViewController so it will appear with UINavigationBar and inside of UITabBar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to place each of your view controllers inside a navigation controller.

E.g. currently you have a TabBarViewController
and two view controllers:

- ViewControllerA
- ViewControllerB

What you need to do is to embed each of them inside a navigation controller so you would have:

- UINavigationController -> ViewControllerA
- UINavigationController -> ViewControllerB

In order to push a new controller you would do:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

let navViewController = myTabBar.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
navViewController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm doing that in AppDelegate, so `myTabBar` is not visible from here. Can I to put `UITabBarController` instead?

Comment: @J.Doe you can get it in this way: `let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController`

Comment: Good answer, saved my day.

Comment: Great Answer, saved my day too!

Answer (score 0):

> `Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1a899b818) to 'UINavigationController'`

Your root view controller is of type [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller).
Therefore you have to use the appropriate methods of this class and not UINavigationController.
To set view controllers use either

`var viewControllers: [UIViewController]?` or

`func setViewControllers([UIViewController]?, animated: Bool)`.

To have a navigation bar you have to instantiate a UINavigationController and add your view controller to this navigation controller. 
Then add your navigation controller to your UITabBarController with via one of the above options.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is UITabBarController 
You can add this:

```
private func showViewController() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "queueTableViewController") as? QueueTableViewController else { return }
    let navVC = self.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
    navVC?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

This will allow you to go to any VC

The second solution is something like this. 
Here You will show the last VC and from there push some VC.

```
    guard let tabCount = viewControllers?.count, tabCount > 1 else { return }
    selectedIndex = tabCount - 1
    if let navigationController = viewControllers?[selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
        if let accountVC = navigationController.visibleViewController as? FirstViewController {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController") as? SomeViewController else { return }
            accountVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```